# JQuery suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

From someone reason, my javascript hasn't been working right. I isolated and cleaned everything up but am stuck with this. Rather then trying to figure out what it is that's causing this (already spent hours on it), I've decided to just figure out a better way. After all, there's more than one way to skin a cat, right? **Here's what I'm trying to do. Have something go from 0 width then back to 100% width.** It works but for some reason, it goes back to 0 in my app

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THnvz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stretcher").each(function () {
        $(".stretcher")
            .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth")
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

**Just looking for a cleaner simpler way that will work. Any suggestions?**

Comment: The foreach loop is excessive.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle that does what your app does?

Comment: So the sequence should be 100% > 0 > 100%, or 0 > 100% > 0?

Comment: @Johan I know. Any help cleaning this up?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sequence should just be (it starts at 100% using css) 0 -> back to 100%

Comment: @j08691 What do you mean? It's a pretty big app (I'm using Rails)

Comment: For every `.stretcher` element, you're re-selecting all the `.stretcher` elements, and performing the operation on all of them. So if there are 20 `.stretcher`s, then you're applying that code to each `.stretcher` 20 times.

Comment: ...and why are you using `.data()` like this? Is there some other area in your application where you need to retrieve this information?

Comment: I mean a fiddle that does what you want it to do isn't much help. We need a fiddle that has the problem, not the desired solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using only CSS3

Change your CSS to:

```
.stretcher {
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:10px;
    animation: firstchange 2s linear;
    -webkit-animation: firstchange 2s linear;
    -moz-animation: firstchange 2s linear;
}

@keyframes firstchange
{
0% {width:100%}
50% {width:0}
100% {width:100%}
}

@-webkit-keyframes firstchange /* Safari and Chrome */
{
0% {width:100%}
50% {width:0}
100% {width:100%}
}

@-moz-keyframes firstchange /* Firefox */
{
0% {width:100%}
50% {width:0}
100% {width:100%}
}
```

You dont need any JavaScript. This should work

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$(this)` consistently within the loop.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stretcher").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this
            .data("origWidth", $this.width())
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: $this.data("origWidth")
            }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Your original code was animating *every* stretcher simultaneously with the widths of each other.

You could also use an ordinary variable instead of saving the width in `.data()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".stretcher").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var orig_width = $this.width();
        $this
            .width(0)
            .animate({
                width: orig_width
            }, 2000);
    });
});
```